# General solution of $(x^2-y^2)dx + (3xy)dy = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution to the homogeneous differential equation

$$(x^2-y^2)dx + (3xy)dy = 0$$

The differential equation does not seem to be separable, and I'm having a tough time to put it in the general form of

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + p(x)y = f(x)$$

Would someone mind offering me some assistance?

Thank you

Comment: Since it is homogeneous, try letting $v=\frac{y}{x}$ so $y=vx$.

Comment: @user57404 The equation is only exact if $$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$ This is not the case

Comment: Ah, I thought the right side was 2xy. Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user84413 suggested. This approach should work.
\begin{align}
(x^2-y^2)\mathrm{dx} + (3xy) \mathrm{dy}&=0 &&\;\left|\cdot \frac{1}{x^2} \right.\\
\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2\right)\mathrm{dx} + 3\frac{y}{x}\mathrm{dy}&=0 &&\;\left|\cdot \frac{1}{\mathrm{dx}}\right.\\
&\vdots\\
\frac{\mathrm{dy}}{dx} &= \left(\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2-1\right)\frac{1}{3}\frac{x}{y}
&&\;\left|u = \frac{y}{x},\frac{\mathrm{dy}}{\mathrm{dx}} =\frac{\mathrm{du}}{\mathrm{dx}}x + u\right.\\
\frac{\mathrm{du}}{\mathrm{dx}}x + u &= \frac{u^2-1}{3u} 
\end{align}
Hope you can work out the rest of the work.